# Skype Tool Messages not sending

Tags: c#, skype4com

I'm trying to code a Skype Tool in C# with the SKYPE4COMLib. It is showing me the messages in Skype, but they keep loading all the time. Any ideas how to fix that? 
My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

namespace SkypeTool
{
public partial class mainmenu : Form
{

    Skype skype = new Skype();


    public mainmenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skype.Attach(5, false);
        status.Text = "connected";

    }


    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        skype.SendMessage("censored", "Test");

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for almost everyone. I think it's because of the skype update. There is a way to **"Fix It"** you can use open message dialog in skype4com. It will look like this.

```
Skype.Client.OpenMessageDialog(name goes here, message goes here);   
Skype.Client.Focus();     
Sendkeys.Send("Key that u want to use to send message")
```

You Can Also See this here [How To: Fix Skype4Com SendMessage Problem!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0zNxk8JMik)